# Which approach to use on a provider with entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, provider

I have a class:

```
public class Tool
{
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My provider has two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Tool> GetFirst()
{
    using (var db = new Entitites())
    {
        return db.Tools.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public void Update(Tool o)
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        db.Tools.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It doesn't work because they are on different contexts, the parameter on `Update` method is not even being used. I can however get the object from the database and change the fields one by one with the parameter object then save changes.

What should I do?

- Update the object and save?
- Keep only one context on providers?
- Another approach?

Comment: Use same context for both methods. Is there any challenge in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `attach` method from [another question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/89b7087a-1b08-4fe0-9cc3-68986fe89a74), quite similar

```
using (var db = new Entitites())
{
    // Attach the object on this context
    db.Attach(tool);

    // Change the state of the context to ensure update
    db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(tool).SetModified();

    // ClientWins, flawless victory
    db.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, tool);
}
```